# run executeable jar with a linux script

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, sh

I wrote a little java program and now I want to execute this .jar file from a .sh script.

my script:

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar /var/spool/sms/sentSMS.jar
```

then i run the command: sudo bash sentSMS.sh
an get following error:

> ERROR: Unable to access jarfile /var/spool/sms/sentSMS.jar

I am using a `Raspberry` with `raspian-jessie`, if this important to solve it.

Sorry, but I'm new in scripting with linux.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that the user must have at least READ permissions on that file.
Also, as you say you are new in linux, make sure the name is correct. sentSMS.jar is different from sentsms.jar

Comment: He's using `sudo`, so root needs read permission, not the user.

Comment: Correct @childofsoong !!

Comment: Hi, thanks. I used `sudo chown pi /var/..` . For the jar and for the sh file. Is there a differense to read permission? Now pi is the owner or?

Comment: You can see the owner of the file with "ls -l <file_name>" . Anyway, check as well that the jar file is not corrupted. Just to make sure you have read permissions, execute "chmod 775 <file_name>"

Comment: Okay, I tried it but I had to do something else.
Afer changing the script to:
`#! /bin/bash
c=$(java -jar /var/spool/sms/sentSMS.jar)` it worked.